# Maven javacTask: source release 1.7 requires target release 1.7

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

When I try building my Java project using Maven, I'm getting the following error:

javacTask: source release 1.7 requires target release 1.7

In my pom file, I have defined source and target for 1.7.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
```

However, when using the maven plugin in Eclipse, I do not run into this error and my code builds without any errors. I'm thinking this is due to something particular to Maven itself on my local machine. Any ideas what could be the root cause of this?

Comment: how do you launch your maven task when you get this error ?

Comment: I've also tried with mvn clean deploy, and mvn clean install -U

Comment: what does `mvn --version` return ?

Comment: Is the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` set correctly (to a JDK 7 or newer installation dir)? Maven uses it to find the JDK.

Comment: This is an error reported by javac from the JDK.  The Maven plugin for Eclipse does not use javac but the built-in compiler, so the behavior is differen.t